# J-link Failed to attach to CPU, connect under reset failed

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, segger-jlink

Trying to connect to J-Link to my PCB and when trying to connect, this is message appears. Was able to connect and flash the drive, but after like 30 seconds, when trying to connect again, this error occurs. And since then, I am not able to connect properly

Here is the message that I received:

[Connection Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxSdu.png)

So, I have two boards, the expected response came from that board.

Expected response:

[Connection Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRm6f.png)

There is a solution I found, but this does not make sense to me since I know little about the Segger J-Link connector's Pin diagram and the same J-Link setup worked on another board, so it does not make sense that the issue is with the J-Link connector.

Found solution (but does not help my case):
*The problem is the NRST of the MCU is not connected to the RESET pin of the J-Link connector.

Comment: Does the connect work if you hold the MCU in reset manually (e.g. if the board has a "Reset" button)?
Is this 2x the same board? Or are this 2 different PCBs with the same MCU?